# Routing : requirement for "methods" must be a string

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently updating one of my projects from Symfony2 to Symfony3. Most of the work is done but there is some kind of error I don't understand.

For the routing configuration file, I read the official documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements) which is telling me to write this configuration :

```
corbins_characters_new_character:
    path: /characters/new
    defaults: { _controller: CorbinsCharacterBundle:Character:new }
    requirements:
        methods: [GET]

corbins_characters_new_character:
    path: /characters
    defaults: { _controller: CorbinsCharacterBundle:Character:create }
    requirements:
        methods: [POST]
```

But when I do, I have the following error :

```
Routing requirement for "methods" must be a string in C:\Developpement\Symfony2\Corbins_V3\src\Corbins\CharacterBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml (which is being imported from "C:\Developpement\Symfony2\Corbins_V3\app/config\routing.yml").

InvalidArgumentException: Routing requirement for "methods" must be a string.
 - in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Routing\Route.php at line 571
```

I was going to create a new issue for Symfony but first I want to ask for help here :D !

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure that this error is triggered by that route? The exception should only be triggered when the `requirements` key is parsed (which isn't present in your example route).

Comment: @xabbuh : I'm going to edit my post to let you see my whole file and the whole error !

Comment: @Federico : Yes I did :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Doc it says methods is not a child of requirements it is just a parent key.

```
corbins_characters_new_character:
    path: /characters
    defaults: { _controller: CorbinsCharacterBundle:Character:create }
    methods: [POST]
```

Could you please check http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements with yml configuration.

Comment: How stupid am I :S ! I try it at home this evening and I validate your answer :) !

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was a bit tired I believe when I wrote this code XD !